# How to enable to use underscore in console in Chrome developer tool?

Tags: angular, google-chrome-console

I'm using Angular2 and underscore,

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';
```

and I want to use the underscore library in Chrome console window too.
Even I do break on a middle of the code, and try to use *, but I got '* is not defined' error.

Is it possible I can use the underscore in Chrome console window? how?

Comment: `window._ = _`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can simply do it by adding *underscore.js* script onto the head of your page:

1) Go to *Chrome Console* of the page you wish to debug.

2) Run this script to import *underscorejs* so that the console starts recognizing `_` commands:

```
var s = document.createElement('script'); 
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js';
document.head.appendChild(s);
```

Alternatively, you can save such *import script* code inside a *snippet* for further usage:

Go to **source** tab, select **snippet** sub-tab, click on `+` to add a new snippet, then add the following code and save:

```
(function () {
  if (typeof window._ === 'undefined') {    
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js';
    document.head.appendChild(s);
  }
}());
```

This way, whenever you need to debug a page using an external library, you can simply add it by running its correspondent snippet!

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51926317/using-underscore-js-in-chrome-console) - what does `window.R` refer to? Did you mean `window._`?

Comment: If you get a `failed to load` error I tried using an updated minified link from underscore and it worked out fine. I used: `https://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js`

Comment: when I run the snippet the underscore js file download freezes on 'pending'.  When I let my page completely load then it finished downloading the underscore script, but by then I'm no longer debugging.  I can't find a way to get the underscore script to finish loading while I'm debugging.

Comment: Never mind.  I got it to work by putting another break point much earlier in my code.

Answer (score 1):

To use underscore.js into chrome console for practice.
Step 1: Open https://underscorejs.org/
Step 2: Now open console and we can use underscore function to it.