# Using underscore.js in chrome console

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, google-chrome-console

I am learning JavaScript and came to a point wherein I have to load underscore.js in the chrome console. I did some search and ended at this stackflow response: [How to enable to use underscore in console in Chrome developer tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847516/how-to-enable-to-use-underscore-in-console-in-chrome-developer-tool/51923914#51923914)

The code snippet provided in the above link works for me. But I could not figure out what does window.R object refer to? Why do I need to include this? Can't I just add the script element and load the underscorejs?

I am referring the below piece of code in the stackoverflow response provided. thanks!

```
(function () {
  if (typeof window.R === 'undefined') {    
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js';
    document.head.appendChild(s);
    }
}());
```

Comment: Underscore does not appear to create any `window.R`. I think the answer's code is wrong - the check should be for `window._` instead.

Comment: agree we should check `window._` instead. you line #2 should be like `if ( window._ === undefined ) {    `

Comment: Yes right, it's a typo and should be window._: means that if window object doesn't contain underscore variable, then add its related script to the head of your document. If anything still not clear please tell

Comment: thank you! for the responses! this is clear for me now